# MariaDb UPDATE not found with LIMIT

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to make this statement in MariaDB because I have to put it in a prodecure with `While` to do a autoincrement, but I get the following error:

> 1093 - Table 'piscina' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

The code is:

```
UPDATE pool set number= 0, code_partner= 900000 
WHERE id_member = 
(Select id_member from pool
where code_partner is null
order by id_member ASC limit 0,1)
```

This other example says "Error in your SQL syntax":

```
UPDATE pool set number = 0, code_partner = 900000 
WHERE code_partner is null 
order by id_person ASC limit 0,1
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, both before and after the UPDATE. (As formatted text.)

Comment: I have not understood you, sorry

Comment: Post examples of what data you currently have in the table, and what data you want to have in it once the `update` succeeds.

Comment: Is `pool` a `VIEW`?  If so, please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.  Otherwise, I don't understand your reference to `piscina`.  Also, you mention a `WHILE` without showing us the Stored Routine.  And `AUTO_INCREMENT` without showing us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.